# Ubuntu vs HiveOS NVIDIA GPU Undervolting, how?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I've been search a lot about this, but seems that no one knows how Hive OS guys do this trick. A lot of places and articles says that nvidia linux driver don't support core voltage controls, which seems true, however, Hive OS can do it, and its based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Any ideas how to undervolting nvidia GPUs in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voltage adjustment is **not** available for discrete NVIDIA GPUs under Linux.

It is available only for AMD GPUs.

https://hiveos.farm/getting_started-start_oc/#overclocking-nvidia-gpus